# Spring AntPathMatcher behavior

Tags: java, spring-boot

At startup, our application is calling `PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver`in order to dynamically discover Resources on the classpath.

Within `org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.doRetrieveMatchingFiles(String, File, Set<File>)`, the following is never true:

[image]

Note that I was running our application from Eclipse.

I made a sample test by using the same value as seen in `fullPattern` and `currPath` variables, and it worked. The test was following:

```
import org.springframework.util.AntPathMatcher;

public class DummyTest {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

         AntPathMatcher m = new AntPathMatcher();

          String pattern = "C:/temp/target/classes/com/test/dummy/**/myFile.xml";
          String path = "C:/temp/target/classes/com/test/dummy/anotherRep/myFile.xml";

          if(m.match(pattern, path)) {
                System.out.println("match");
           }
           else {
                 System.out.println("doesn't match");
           }
}
```

}

Does anyone have an idea why it doesn't work in context of my application?